# How Do I make my Nav Menu option change color or background when I click on it using Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here is my current nav menu created using JS.

```
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const items = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4"];

items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const el = document.createElement("a");
  el.innerText = item;
  el.classList.add("menu-items");
  el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
  el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;
  navList.appendChild(el);
});
```

Basically, how do I make my nav menu active whenever I click it?

I saw [this example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_active_element2), but I don't see how to implement this with my current menu I created using JS.

Is this the only way or is there another method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a class with the style you need:

```
.highlighted {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

And a click event on a parent element that checks the target. You also may want to remove the highlight on the other elements before.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var highlighted = document.querySelector(".menu-items.highlighted");
  if (highlighted) highlighted.classList.remove("highlighted");
  if (event.target.classList.contains('menu-items')) {
    event.target.classList.add("highlighted");
  } 
});
```